# DLL error at Publishing nopcommerce 3.80 fresh code

Tags: publish, nopcommerce-3.80

I've download nopCommerce 3.80 fresh code from github and publishing it from Visual Studio 2017 framework and I'm getting DLL related error.

Here are error messages.

------ Build started: Project: Nop.Services, Configuration: Release Any CPU

**SGEN : error : Could not load file or assembly** ..\nopCommerce_3.80_Source\packages\EPPlus.4.1.0\lib\net40\EPPlus.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Build started: Project: Nop.Web.Framework, Configuration: Release Any CPU

**CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file** '..\nopCommerce_3.80_Source\Libraries\Nop.Services\bin\Release\Nop.Services.dll' could not be found

------ Build started: Project: Nop.Web, Configuration: Release Any CPU

**CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file** '..\nopCommerce_3.80_Source\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\bin\Release\Nop.Web.Framework.dll' could not be found
4>------ Skipped Publish: Project Nop.Web, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------**

Solution is successfully building in debug and build mode.

What can be wrong with DLL at publish time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution by unblocking the error dll file by right click of that dll in their properties option.